# create virtual or fake schema in oracle

Tags: oracle, schema, synonym

I have the following question: 
Within my application (for reference: c++ and occi though irrelevant for the question) I have queries that access multiple oracle database schemata at the same time. One of these queries has the (simplified) structure:

```
SELECT MAX(COL_A) FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL SELECT MAX(COL_B) SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B;
```

`TABLE_A` comes from `SCHEMA_A`. I now created a replica of this `SCHEMA_A` on a test DB and would like to test the application with it.

The problem is that `SCHEMA_B` is not under my control and is not visible from this test DB.

Is there a way to create a `TABLE_B` inside `SCHEMA_A` so that it can be queried like in the above, i.e. almost as if there was a `SCHEMA_B` which in reality doesn't exit in that DB?

One possible way to circumvent this would probably be to create a synonym inside the production version of `SCHEMA_A` to have

```
CREATE SYNONYM TABLE_B for SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B;
```

then change the query in the application to

```
SELECT MAX(COL_A) FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL SELECT MAX(COL_B) TABLE_B;
```

and then create a `TABLE_B` inside `SCHEMA_A` in the test DB. The problem is that it is not completely straightforward to have things changed in the production DB, so if there would be a way to 'fake' the existence of `SCHEMA_B` on the test DB that would be preferable.

Creating another DB schema in the test DB which is really called `SCHEMA_B` and from which I could then grant select rights to `SCHEMA_A` is not completely excluded, but if I could keep things contained within `SCHEMA_A` that would be preferable.

Comment: You can create a db link to another database https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083

Comment: Create a dblink to your schema_b and if you don’t want to use directly the data from this database use data pump to insert the data from schema B to your test database.